# In the Neon Night VSCode theme, how does he do error dashes instead of squiggles?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I love the dash effect instead of the squiggles in the [Neon Night VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chaseadamsio.vscode-theme-neon-night) theme, but some of the ui colors are a little bright for me.  Anyone know how it is achieving the effect?  I'm trying to apply the effect to a different theme, and have even downloaded/combed through the [GH repo](https://github.com/chaseadamsio/vscode-theme-neon-night), but haven't managed to figure it out.  My apologies if this has already been asked.  If my google-fu is broken, please be kind.

[image: Squiggles as dashes]

Comment: you can look at the files of the Neon theme and find out how they did it

Comment: Right...which I already said that I did.  All I see is where they defined the color, not the style.  I appreciate that you were able to find it, but I was not, which is why I asked my question.

Comment: if the decoration changes when you change theme it has to be somewhere in the extension

Comment: I agree completely.  Since I couldn't pin it down, that's why I asked for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theme author here, this was also posted as an issue on the repo and I wrote the response [on the issue](https://github.com/chaseadamsio/vscode-theme-neon-night/issues/45#issuecomment-785159373).

Here's what I shared...

You want to use these selectors:

`editorError.foreground`: error squiggles
`editorWarning.foreground`: warning squiggles
`editorInfo.foreground`: info squiggles

https://github.com/chaseadamsio/vscode-theme-neon-night/blob/mainline/src/colors/editor.js#L42-L45

you can set these on your workbench too (so you can use your favorite theme without forking) by adding them to your settings.json like this:

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorError.foreground": "#f00"
  }
}
```

You can read more about them [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) and search for "Errors and warnings".

Answer (score 0):

I found the 'offending color'.

```json
"editorUnnecessaryCode.border": "#FF8E8E"
```

I found this by binary elimination of the theme entries.

I think it is implemented with a text Decorator, because I could not find as a style of the `span` with the Developer Tools of VSC.

Comment: This was the same thing ran into when looking at it.  The color was pretty obvious, but the effect was not (and the effect is what I'm looking for).  Because of some problems with my eyes, this style stands out a lot better.  I am, by any definition, not a VSCode development type, but I gave it a go.  Still open for suggestions finding the style.  Thanks for answering. :)

Comment: Holy cow, I'm dumb.  I think I understand.  Many thanks, I'll test and accept after.

Answer (score 0):

The dash decoration is usually created by the semantic code check. Squiggles are the result of syntactic checks. So it's not a theme speciality and would appear similar with other themes.

Hover with the mouse over the dash decoration to see what vscode suggests to do.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was reading, which is why this is throwing me off so much.  The look is definitely coming from this theme somewhere, though.  I looked at it with the inspector even and didn't find anything that looked right either.